# How to make it so if any variable in a list is greater than an integer, it will print out something, else it will print out something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
one = int(input("Type a number"))
two = int(input("Type a second number"))
three = int(input("Type a third number"))
four = int(input("Type fourth number"))
num = [one,two,three,four]
```

How do I make it so if any variable in num is greater than or equal to 7, it will print ("yes")  and else, it will print ("no")? Also I'm not sure if I made a list correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the max() function, you don't need to use any for loops.

```
num = [1, 9, 2, 6, 10]

if max(num) >= 7:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Good news - that list looks correct!

What you're looking for is two things - a for loop and a conditional.

The for loop will look over each item in the list, and the conditional will check to see if the current number is greater than or equal to 7. If so, it can update some value (here, a boolean that evaluates whether a number was greater than 7) that is checked again later. Here is my solution to your problem!

```
# Assume all of the stuff from your question goes here.
isGreaterThan = False
for number in num:
    if number >= 7:
        isGreaterThan = True
        break
if isGreaterThan:
    print("Yes!")
else:
    print("No.")
```

If you don't get what any part of this does, please ask!

Comment: I like the idea, but the implementation is all wrong. For example, True instead of true. For another, you mean to use `number` within the loop, of course.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I've made the edits as needed.
Again, thanks. I don't want to provide bad/non-working answers, so I welcome the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **for loop** to go through each item in the list to check whether an item is greater or equal to 7. Then use Booleans to print out the proper output

```py
isGreaterThan = False
for i in num:
     if i >= 7:
        isGreaterThan = True
        break
    
if isGreaterThan:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in num: # loop through all the elements in the list
if(n > 7): # each element is in the "n" variable - cehck if n>7
    print("yes") # if yes, then pront it
    break # break the loop and stop looking
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    one = int(input("Type a number"))
two = int(input("Type a second number"))
three = int(input("Type a third number"))
four = int(input("Type fourth number"))
num = [one,two,three,four]
x= 7
for i in num:
    if i>x:
        print(f"your  {i}th number is grater than {i} ")
    else:
        pass
    x = x +1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the shorthand way:

```py
num = [1, 9, 2]

print("Yes" if any(n >= 7 for n in num) else "No")
```

Alternatively, using the builtin `max` as suggested by another answer:

```
print("Yes" if max(num) >= 7 else "No")
```

For a quick test, I'd encourage you to lower the 2nd element in the list, and check how the output changes.